# C++ While loop Not Exiting if "\r" is found

Tags: c++, while-loop

I need to parse an input which which is a vector of strings each new line is an element in the vector and I need to split it up in individual vectors based on new lines

Input vector

```
0.01 0.99

0.02 0.98

0.001 0.999
0.29 0.71
0.94 0.06
0.95 0.05

0.05 0.95
0.9 0.1

0.01 0.99
0.7 0.3
```

Each new blank line means the end of that array and each blank line is a "\r" string.
To parse it I'm using the following.

```
  for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i)
  {
    int LineCount = 0;
    vector<float> EmptyRow;


    while( Input.empty() != true || Input[0] != "\r"  ){

      Tables[i].probs.push_back(EmptyRow);

      istringstream ss(Input[0]);
      string word;

      while (ss >> word) 
      {
        Tables[i].probs[LineCount].push_back( stof(word) );
      }

      LineCount++;
      Input.erase(Input.begin());
      
    } 
    Input.erase(Input.begin()); 
  }
```

how ever the while condition `Input[0] != "\r"` is never triggered so it will never exit the loop.

Any advice on how to resolve this issues or if there is a better way to parse these strings into vectors divided by new lines would be great thanks.

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline

Comment: note that `\r` on itself is not a line break character. `\r` technically means go back to the beginning of the line, while `\n` means move to the next line. Unix systems use `\n` for new line and Windows uses `\r\n`.

Comment: Following on from Timo, it's very possible that the `\r\n` is being stripped and you'll be getting an empty string for the blank lines. If it _isn't_ stripped, and `Input[0]` returns the first character of the line, comparing with `"\r"` is probably wrong. I suspect you want `'\r'`.

Comment: Just in passing, `if (Input.empty() != true)` is usually written `if (!Input.empty())`. The former isn't incorrect, but it's uncommon, hence, confusing to read.

Answer (score 1):

|| will first evaluate `Input.empty() != true` . If that comes out to be false only then it will check `Input[0] != "\r"`.
Solution: use && instead of || . It will evaluate both expressions.

Answer (score 0):

If you want `Input[0] != "\r"` to be triggered, you should use `&&` instead of `||`